# What is proper type for vuex store returned to the vuex plugin during it initialisation

Tags: typescript, vuex

The store initialisation is being done the following way:

```
/* Logic */
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex, { StoreOptions } from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const DataManager = new UserDataManager()

type RootStateType = {
  version: string
}

const store: StoreOptions<RootStateType> = {
  // @ts-ignore
  state: {
    version: '1.0.0'
  },
  modules: {...},
  plugins: [DataManager.init()]
}

export default new Vuex.Store<RootStateType>(store)
```

...while the plugin:

```
export class UserDataManager {
  ... logic

  public init () {
    return (store: <TYPE?>) => {
      store.watch(
        (state: RootStateType) => {
          return [state.user.authentication.id]
        },
        (watched: string[]) => {
          const userID = watched[0]
          ... logic
        }
      )
    }
  }
}
```

I am a bit puzzled if somehow the proper type can be passed here? I've tried passing to it:

```
type storeType = StoreOptions<RootStateType>

...
    return (store: storeType) => {
...
```

but it returns:
`TS2339: Property 'watch' does not exist on type 'StoreOptions<RootStateType>'`
I will appreciate a lot if somebody can share some ideas on this topic :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peeked at [vuex-persist](https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-persist/blob/master/src/index.ts), and `Store<RootStateType>` should work.

Comment: Indeed this is the way :-)